# WPF: Send arguments to a background thread and get output after it is started

Tags: c#, python, wpf, multithreading, exe

I have a deep-learning model written with python and it needs a path of a video as its input. I am trying to create a GUI for this model using WPF, and the model has been converted to an application file.

Because the time for model to import packages is too long, I want to start a process of the python application file while initialising the WPF main window. Then, I can record a video and send a path of this video to this process, and after I get a output from this model, I can recording an another video and send a new path to the model again.

I have tried using backgroundworker and thread, but both of them can only send arguments when the process is initialised, and neither of them can send arguments to the background process while the process is being executed. And Only after the process is finished, I can get the output from the background thread.

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Process p_exe = new Process();
    p_exe.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:/dist/predict/predict.exe";
    p_exe.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p_exe.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p_exe.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    p_exe.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p_exe.StartInfo.Arguments = e.Argument.ToString();
    p_exe.Start();

    e.Result = p_exe.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    p_exe.WaitForExit();
    p_exe.Close();

}
```

How can I send arguments to and get output from the background thread while the process is being executed?

Comment: You don't need to run a BackgroundWorker or any other background thread just to wait for the termination of a Process. Just start it and attach an [Exited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited?view=netframework-4.8) event handler. See the [Example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput?view=netframework-4.8#examples) for how to write to the process StandardInput stream.

Comment: Use the [Output​Data​Received](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived?view=netframework-4.8) event to get notified when the process writes output.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I failed to implement it in this way, and It seemed that the exe was not executed if I put it in a loop to receive the video path. I am trying to get it in other ways, and I will update my question if I make some progress.